# Jquery File Upload Plugin - File Delete - Authorization header

Tags: jquery, file, jquery-plugins, upload

I am using jquery file upload plugin for one of my project, using basic browser authentication for user access control. Once logged in, I am passing the base64 encoded string of username and password across the calls on the user session. Base64 encoded string is sent to server via http authorization header. I was fairly successful in setting authorization header for all the calls except file delete one. Would appreciate, if any one can give pointers in that direction

I am setting the authorization header for other calls as below

```
$('#fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');
  $.ajax({
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
    dataType: 'json',
  type: 'GET',
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', btoa(userId,password));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jquery.fileupload-ui.js file, add the below code in the code block of "Callback for file deletion:"

```
data.beforeSend = function(xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth(userId,userId));
                  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this in another way. I used event which is fired before send delete request and added header to data object

```
$('#fileupload')
    .bind('fileuploaddestroy', function (e, data) {
        data.headers = {
            'Authorization_Token': "any_token"
        };
});
```